# Pandas GroupBy Count of a give Column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to Group By Date and Hour with an aggregation founction `count` and split the result for each different ID (in the columns) in output.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GpID': [1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,0,1,1],
                'HR':  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                'Date_':  [1,1,1,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
               })
```

[image]

The output **format** is **like**

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({ 'HR':  [1,2,3,1,2,3],
                    'Date_':  [1,1,1,2,2,2],
                    'GpID_0': [1,2,5,1,4,2],
                   'GpID_1': [1,2,5,1,4,2],
                   'GpID_2': [4,2,5,1,4,2],

               })
```

[image]

Tried:

```py
# 1st try
df_g = df.groupby(["Hr", "Date_"], observed=False).count().fillna(0).unstack()
# 2nd try
df_g = df.groupby(["Hr", "Date_","GpId"], observed=False).count().fillna(0).unstack(-1)
# 3rd try
df_g = df.groupby(["Hr", "Date_"], observed=False).count().fillna(0).unstack()
```

Nothing accurate yet

Comment: Do you have an attempt?

Comment: Tried 
 df_g =  df.groupby(["Hr, "Date_"], observed=False).count().fillna(0).unstack() and df_g =  df.groupby(["Hr, "Date_","GpId"], observed=False).count().fillna(0).unstack(-1) , and df_g =  df.groupby(["Hr, "Date_"], observed=False).count().fillna(0).unstack()

Noting accurate yet

Comment: Put it in the question.

Comment: I believe the output you gave is not what you tried to explain. `e.g. There is no row where ID=2 and both Date_=1 & HR=1. And in your final df it is written 4 instead of 0 (or Nan)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Believed you tried to do something like this

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'GpID': [1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,1,0,1,2,0,1,1],
                'HR':  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                'Date_':  [1,1,1,2,2,2,2, 2,2,2,2,3,3,3, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
               })
df.loc[:,'Count']=1

pd.pivot_table(df, values='Count', index=['Date_', 'HR'], columns=['GpID'], aggfunc='count').fillna(0).reset_index()

Out [1]:
        Date_   HR  0   1   2
0       1       1   1   2   0
1       2       1   1   3   0
2       2       2   0   2   2
3       3       1   0   2   1
4       3       2   1   2   1
5       3       3   1   2   0
```